# Proof of nonexistence of holomorphic continuation.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, analytic-continuation

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a domain and $\emptyset \neq U \subsetneq D$ open. I want to show the existence of a holomorphic function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ without holomorphic continuation to $D$.

**Proof:** Let $z_0 \in D \setminus U$ and consider

$$f: \mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \hspace{15pt} z \mapsto \frac{1}{z - z_0}$$

$f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_0\}$, especially on $U$. Now assume that there exists an holomorphic continuation $g$ of $f|_U$ on $D$. Since $f|_{D\setminus\{z_0\}}$ and $g|_{D\setminus\{z_0\}}$ are holomorphic on the domain $D\setminus\{z_0\}$ the identity theorem for holomorphic functions tells us $f|_{D\setminus\{z_0\}}  \equiv g|_{D\setminus\{z_0\}}$, but there is no continuous and especially no holomorphic continuation of $f_{D\setminus\{z_0\}}$ to $D$ in contradiction to the existence of $g$.

Is my proof correct or can you come up with an easier proof?

Comment: Your proof is correct and it as simple as it can  get.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you!